# tkinter tk wiget turtle python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i am trying to do a turtle game with the tkinter.Tk() class.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

main = Tk(className="Castle Game")

s=turtle.TurtleScreen(cv=main,mode='standard', colormode=1.0, delay=10)
cover=turtle.RawTurtle(s)
```

It tries to return the following:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\2 Computer science\Year 9\4Python\Castle.py", line 7, in <module>
    s=turtle.TurtleScreen(cv=main,mode='standard', colormode=1.0, delay=10)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 989, in __init__
    TurtleScreenBase.__init__(self, cv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 488, in __init__
    self.cv.config(scrollregion = (-w//2, -h//2, w//2, h//2 ))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1263, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-scrollregion"
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

In turtle graphics, the `cv` option stands for canvas, but you're giving it a `Tk`. That's why there's an error. To fix that, you will need to do this:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
root=Tk(className="Castle Game")
main = Canvas(root)
main.pack()
s=turtle.TurtleScreen(cv=main,mode='standard', colormode=1.0, delay=10)
cover=turtle.RawTurtle(s)
```

By changing `main` to `Canvas` and pack it onto a root.